# Need to Restart PhantomjS when it hangs

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, capybara, site-prism

I want to restart my Phantomjs Driver when it hangs. I have an example of restarting poltergiest as below:

```
if driver.is_a?(Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver)
driver.restart
end
```

I am not using Poltergeist driver. I am using phantomjs driver object like this below:

```
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :phantomjs)
```

I need to know how to restart phantomjs driver.  I need something like this:

```
Capybara.page.driver.restart.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.driver.quit` should quit the selenium::webdriver instance which should then automatically start a new one the next time the session is used.

Comment: Tom, It is quitting the driver and open again but immediately i got below error and quit the driver again.                                                                                                                      #<Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError: no such session

Comment: Also, if running less that selenium 2.50 - try updating

Comment: Happening same thing using selenium 2.50 . Looks like when it quits the driver object, it lost the session. Just emailed you in details....

Comment: ok -- so it's failing attempting to connect to phantomjs maybe? did you upgrade to the latest selenium? if so, then we really need a stacktrace to have any clue whats going on

Comment: This is the logs i do have :         **Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9524 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)**
      **/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'**
      
    I have updated to gem 'selenium-webdriver',   '=2.50.0'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102631/discussion-between-saeek-and-tom-walpole).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned method to restart phantomjs

```
def restart_phantomjs
    puts "-> Restarting phantomjs: iterating through capybara sessions..."
    session_pool = Capybara.send('session_pool')
    session_pool.each do |mode,session|
      msg = "  => #{mode} -- "
      driver = session.driver
      if driver.is_a?(Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver)
        msg += "restarting"
        driver.restart
      else
        msg += "not poltergeist: #{driver.class}"
      end
      puts msg
    end
  end
  module_function :restart_phantomjs
end
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. As i mentioned, i am not using Poltergiest driver. So this will not help. "Tom Walpole" already provided me a good solution which worked partially. Still encountering other issue though.